# In IOS track user location in Google Map

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using google map SDKs in my iOS project to track the user location and a draw a route line of the user path for his movement.I want to add two images for the starting point of the user and another for user movement. I can't add these images.Please help me to add these images. Here is my code:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

//get the latest location
CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

//store latest location in stored track array;
[self.locations addObject:currentLocation];

//get latest location coordinates
CLLocationDegrees Latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees Longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
CLLocationCoordinate2D locationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Latitude, Longitude);

//zoom map to show users location
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(locationCoordinates, 1000,1000);

MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapview regionThatFits:viewRegion];
[mapview setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];


NSInteger numberOfSteps = self.locations.count;

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[numberOfSteps];
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < numberOfSteps; index++) {
    CLLocation *location = [self.locations objectAtIndex:index];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate2 = location.coordinate;

    coordinates[index] = coordinate2;
}

MKPolyline *polyLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:numberOfSteps];
[mapview addOverlay:polyLine];
```

}

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineView *polylineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc]     initWithPolyline:overlay];
    polylineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    polylineView.lineWidth = 10.0;
    return polylineView;
}
```

This code draw the user path. But I want this type of [output](http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/iOS-6-Maps-turn-by-turn-teaser.jpg). 
Someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add annotations to mapview, for first and last objects of your self.locations array. You will also need to remove the old annotation each time the location is updated to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Let centerY and centerX be the center point for the image

```
CLLocationDegrees offset = 0.01;  // change size here
  CLLocationDegrees southWestY = centerY - offset;
  CLLocationDegrees southWestX = centerX - offset;
  CLLocationDegrees northEastY = centerY + offset;
  CLLocationDegrees northEastX = centerX + offset;

  CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(southWestY,southWestX);
  CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(northEastY,northEastX);
  GMSCoordinateBounds *overlayBounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:southWest coordinate:northEast];

  GMSGroundOverlay *overlay = [GMSGroundOverlay groundOverlayWithBounds:overlayBounds icon:[UIImage imagedNamed:@"YourImage.png"]];
  overlay.bearing = 0;
  overlay.map = self.mapView
```

With this approach (unlike with the marker) the image will zoom in and out as the user zooms in/out of the map.